# Jquery-ui datepicker php+mysql issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui, datepicker

When i set my input field without datepicker like that:

```
<input type="text" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" class="textbox" />
```

I can see my value which i get from database. The format is: 1965-02-05

When I set this code:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        }
            );
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "yearRange", '1900:2011' );
    });
    </script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" class="textbox" />
```

nothing shown in text input area, but i can see datepicker without any problem when i click inside of the text input area.

What is the problem?
I'am formatting like that:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

Comment: please don't say to make this format: yyyy-mm-dd one y describes two digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: '1900:2011',
    constrainInput: false 
});
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/eATRv/

Try this. Now you should also be able to see if it is the correct format :)

Comment: try pasting the value of the input field :)

Comment: Does this -> http://jsfiddle.net/eATRv/ not work in your browser? Please paste the input value you get from your code

Comment: It works on my browser bu not working in my code i did not solve the problem than i switch to that plug-in http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html it works now...

Comment: Heh ok. Sure that none of the other plugins you use interfere with it? JQUI Datepicker is such a nice plugin :)